# How to pass Textfields values from form to .java class in Tapestry?

Tags: tapestry

As I am new to Tapestry I dont have much knowledge aboutr it.I have a login.tml file in which i have two textfields userName and password.I need to pass values of textfields to login.java class when user clicks on submit or actionlink.Please give me the code for login.tml and login.java in Tapestry.
 Thanx in advance

Comment: "Please send me teh codes"-type questions do not usually get you good answers, because others perceive them as rude. Instead, describe what you have tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Conincidentally, the [forms page in the official documentation](http://tapestry.apache.org/forms-and-validation.html#FormsandValidation-StoringDataBetweenRequests) contains a basic example just like that.

Comment: Well I have tried like this also..but unable to get values.I badly need it.If u can please help me in some other way

Comment: i have written many events in login.java.but no one in actually is getting called.can someone pls tell me how to resolve this pblm.

Comment: Your code looks alright to me. Short of actually doing your work, I don't think there's anything else I could do for you.

Comment: Ok thanx..i'll look into it.One more problem I am facing.I am using Tapestry 5 and i want to use shiro-security (tynamo 0.4.x) for my application .I have referred some docs and examples too but couldn't found right way to proceed.If u have some sample code please share.I want step by step configuration to move on as i have never did it before..Please help.Also my UI application is separate I am using RESTful web services